Refresh slowness of materialized view that select latest row for each group in a large table
I have a materialized view defined like this:

CREATE materialized VIEW order
AS SELECT *
   FROM ( SELECT *, pg_catalog.row_number()
          OVER( 
          PARTITION BY flow_id, order_id
          ORDER BY timestamp desc, msg_seq_num desc) AS last_op_order
           FROM trades) derived_table1
  WHERE derived_table1.last_op_order = 1


However, Redshift will create new table every time when the view is refreshing because it is using windows function and also aggregation, just wonder is it possible to have incremental refresh for this kind of operation?
